# How does SQL subqueries use outside variables

Tags: sql

```
select sName, GPA, sID
from Student S1
where not exists (select sName from Student S2 where S2.GPA > S1.GPA)
```

Say the above query.  How does the following line work?

```
(select sName from Student S2 where S2.GPA > S1.GPA)
```

Is a new table that is the cross product or S1 and S2 created and the GPA compared then returned?  I don't understand how S2 can be compared to S1 when S1 is not part of the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *correlated subquery*.

You can think of it as a nested loop.  For each row in the outer table, the subquery is run.  And when it is run, the value of `S1.GPA` is the value from the row in the outer query.

So, the subquery returns one or more rows that have a higher GPA.  If there are no such rows, then the `GPA` in the outer query is the highest one!  Voila!  One way to get the students with the maximum GPA.

Although you can understand the execution as a nested loop, the SQL optimizer does not need to use a nested loop to run such a query.  For instance, if there is an index on `Student(GPA)` then the query might be quite fast.

Comment: Does the parameter for the inner select matter?  Like select GPA instead of sName still returns the same thing?

Comment: @bakalolo . . . It changes the logic of the query, but any column can be used.